# removeClass removing the incorrect class

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/a86C3/

```
    var classNames = ['mute', 'on', 'off', 'none'];
    $('.state').click(function () {

        $(this).toggleClass(function (i, className) {
            var index = (classNames.indexOf(className) + 1) % classNames.length;

            alert(className);
            $(this).removeClass(className);

            return classNames[index];
        });
    });
```

The .state should be preserved. Why this class is removed initially?

Comment: What the heck is that supposed to do ?

Comment: the state class should be preserved always. Only change the mute, on, off and none. Everything else works fine.

Comment: `className` contains all classes of the tag... getting index of that in classNames array breaks your code

Comment: I will add state to classNames. state mute, state on, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why this class is removed initially?

Lets go through it step by step:

1. `className` is `"mute state"`.
2. `classNames.indexOf("mute state")` is `-1` and therefore `index` is `0`.
3. `$(this).removeClass("mute state");` removes both `mute` and `state`.
4. `classNames[0]` is returned, which is `mute`. Since you just removed `mute`, `toggleClass` will add it back again.

The end result is that `state` is removed.

---

You probably don't want to call `removeClass` inside `toggleClass` and `className` is not a single class, its a string containing all classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    var classNames = ['mute', 'on', 'off', 'none'];
    var counter = -1;
    var newClass, oldClass;
    $('.state').click(function () {

        $(this).toggleClass(function (i, className) {
            counter++;

            oldClass = newClass || classNames[counter % classNames.length];
            newClass = classNames[counter % classNames.length];

            $(this).removeClass(oldClass);

            return classNames[counter % classNames.length];
        });
    });
```

Do you mean something like above? http://jsfiddle.net/Dieterg/a86C3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it :

```
var classNames = ['mute', 'on', 'off', 'none'];
$('.state').on('click', function () {
    var k = 0, self = this;

    $.each(classNames, function (i, klass) {
        if ($(self).hasClass(klass)) k = i;
    });

    $(this).removeClass(classNames[k]).addClass(classNames[k==(classNames.length-1) ? 1 : 1+k]);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a86C3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess :

```
$(this).toggleClass(function (i, className) {       
    className = className.match(new RegExp(
        '(?:^|\\s)(' + classNames.join('|') + ')(?=\\s|$)'
    ))[1];
    $(this).removeClass(className);
    return classNames[
        (classNames.indexOf(className) + 1) % classNames.length
    ];
});
```

And a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/QZ8Kh/.

---

Bonus :

```
var classNames = ['mute', 'on', 'off', 'none'];
$('.state').click(function () {
    var className = $(this).attr('class').match(new RegExp(
        '(?:^|\\s)(' + classNames.join('|') + ')(?=\\s|$)'
    ))[1];
    $(this).toggleClass(className + ' ' + classNames[
        (classNames.indexOf(className) + 1) % classNames.length
    ]);
});
```